# plpython3u path issue with network drive

Tags: python, postgresql, mkdir, plpython

I have a working postgres trigger for folder operations on local drives. I would like to move these operations to a network drive where K is a network drive:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION "public"."_copy_folderstructure_ms_mus_dslam_kserver"()
  RETURNS "pg_catalog"."trigger" AS $BODY$
import shutil
import os
import time
try:
    if not os.path.exists("k:/SWBT/musbt_projects/" + TD["new"]["ff6ff"]):
        os.makedirs("k:/SWBT/musbt_projects/" + TD["new"]["ff6ff"])
        time.sleep(1)
        os.makedirs("k:/SWBT/musbt_projects/" + TD["new"]["ff6ff"] + "/" + TD["new"]["f3410"])
        time.sleep(1)
        print("ok")
except:
    print("fail")
try:
    if (TD["new"]["created_at"] != TD["new"]["updated_at"]):
        print("ok")
    elif (TD["new"]["created_at"] == TD["new"]["updated_at"]):
        shutil.copytree("k:/SWBT/musbt_projects/Templates/musnumber_pcpnumber","k:/SWBT/musbt_projects/" + TD["new"]["ff6ff"] + "/" + TD["new"]["f3410"])
        time.sleep(1)
        shutil.copy("k:/SWBT/musbt_projects/Templates/costing_sheet_templates" + "/" + TD["new"]["f4465"] + ".xls","k:/SWBT/musbt_projects/" + TD["new"]["ff6ff"] + "/" + TD["new"]["f3410"] + "/" + TD["new"]["f3410"] + "_cost.xls" )
except:
    print("fail")
$BODY$
  LANGUAGE plpython3u VOLATILE
  COST 100
```

This code is not generating any error or result assuming I use the network path in a wrong way? (However it is mounted as K drive) I've also tried using `//192.168.16.253/clients2` instead of `k:/` Any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: Have you done any basic debugging? There’s no way for us to reproduce this, right, so you’re going to have to try some things.

Comment: how can I do that from postgres? I cannot see anything in the logs. The drive is accessible from python console, I've checked that.